# JQuery - IE6 - How to FadeOut and FadeIn simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, effects, fadeout

I have a sequence of position absolute div, say

```
<div>...</div>
<div style="display:none">...</div>
<div style="display:none">...</div>
<div style="display:none">...</div>
```

I wrote a simple slide code using jQuery

```
currentDiv.fadeOut('slow');
nextDiv.fadeIn('slow');
```

It works perfectly in FF/Chrome/Safari/IE7/IE8, but not in IE6. I found in IE6, fadeOut and fadeIn not occur simultaneously as in other browsers, fadeIn always begin after fadeOut is completed. any ideas?

Comment: Please do not develop for Internet Explorer 6. Developers **must** force users to use a **working** web browser.

Comment: @Alan -there's a lot more than developer preferences at work in the world.  Politicshave a much bigger effect...

Comment: @Alan. I work for an organisation with 500+ staff using IE6 because that is all the company provides, so have to develop for that. Can you please advise the best way to 'force' the entire company to change? @Relax is being thorough, and should quite rightly get his code to work on IE6. Stats are that a very large number of people are still using this browswer.

Comment: @Alan - I work for a variety of US government agencies who still run IE6 on private networks for thousands of users.  IE6 is a fact of life for some of us.

Comment: I realize you have to do what you have to do, but I'd be very interested to see the stats that show that a very large number of people are still using IE6.

Comment: Discussion: support or not... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611/ie6-to-support-or-not-to-support

Comment: And unfortunately you will continue to support IE 6 until you make the decision not to. The only problem is that there is some other schmuck who is willing to support and he will get the business/position or it will get outsourced. I have decided to not support IE 6 otherwise I will still be supporting it in 10 years time. Short term gain = long term pain.

Comment: All points noted above are valuable. It is the politics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this example and both a fadeIn and fadeOut work at the same time in IE6:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(document.body).click(function () {
        $("div#one").fadeOut("slow");
        $("div#two").fadeIn("slow");

      });

    });
</script>
<style>
  span { color:red; cursor:pointer; }
  div { margin:3px; width:80px; display:none;
    height:80px; float:left; }
  div#one { background:#f00; display:block;}
  div#two { background:#0f0; }
  div#three { background:#00f; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span>Click here...</span>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I modified the example from: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsoptions

I've noticed before that setting the styles display to none in the actual div instead of in the css file or via jquery can sometimes cause issues. Try just giving each div a class of displaynone instead of setting their style tag. Hopefully this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this site:
http://www.geeksucks.com/toolbox/23-jquery-fade-in-fade-out-effect.htm

?
Here is a goog Plugin for jQuery: 
[http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing your own animation to achieve the fades, rather than using the defaults supplied.  I don't know that it will be any better, but it might be worth a try.

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate